# Complicated MySQL Query on Two Tables

Tags: mysql

I have one table called "offers" with columns "offer_id", "offer" and "hid".
The primary key is "offer_id".

I have another table called "dates" with columns "hid", "date", "offer_id" and some others.
The primary key is "date" and "hid". The same value of "offer_id" can exist in many rows (or none at all).

How can I write a mySQL query to find offer_ids that exist in "offers" but not in "dates"?

I tried

```
SELECT offers.offer_id FROM offers JOIN dates ON offers.offer_id NOT IN dates
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: This might help you understand: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For larger tables this variant will be a lot faster than the `NOT IN`: outer join to `dates` and then filter where `dates.offer_id` is null:

```
SELECT offers.offer_id
FROM offers
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates ON offers.offer_id = dates.offer_id
WHERE dates.offer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Nice, intuitive, clean query.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you.

```
SELECT offers.offer_id FROM offers where offer_id NOT IN (select offer_id from dates)
```

Comment: Too bad that has to run a query on dates for every offer.. Would it work if the inner query was this: (SELECT offer_id FROM dates WHERE dates.offer_id = offers.offer_id) ?? That would surely speed things up.. Though I'm not the "SQL expert" by any means

Comment: Good point @SpencerLockhart doing a where clause would speed it up.

Comment: It seems ungrateful of me not to accept this answer but I can only choose one. I tested both the solution of graceemile and the one from Robert as modified by @SpencerLockhart and they both gave the same results in the same time. So I really could use either. Actually I am going to use the one I have ticked because of the point about avoiding NOT IN. Thanks to all.

Comment: no worries I would agree using the NOT IN version is the best.